# Dell laptop, Ubuntu 23.10 (Manic Minotaur), frozen on startup

Tags: boot, nvidia, 23.10

Recently (seemingly after the most recent update), my system won't start anymore.

After asking for my bootphrase the machine hangs on the dell logo

I can access the grub menu and get to a terminal via recovery mode, but booting into an older kernel without recovery mode gives a similar booting issue (although the ubuntu symbol is shown beneath the dell logo when booting with an older kernel)

I did have terminal access before (with no usable GUI), but after using `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` succesfully and attempting to reinstall nvidia drivers, this didn't solve the issue and actually prevented me from using  <kbd>ctrl</kbd>    <kbd>alt</kbd>   <kbd>f3</kbd>  to access the terminal.

A few years ago there was a problem with the nvidia drivers and a kernel mismatch, and output from `journalctl -xb` if I search for 'nvidia' (below), and the presence of an nvidia logfile (also below) in the home directory of the 'rescue mode', does suggest I could be facing a similar issue again. Although this may not necessarily be the problem. I have access to the whole `journalctl -xb` output and the nvidia logfile, if there are other parts which will be useful to add here.

```
Jan 10 23:01:52 IT096060 kernel: nvidia: loading out-of-tree module taints kernel.
Jan 10 23:01:52 IT096060 kernel: nvidia: module license 'NVIDIA' taints kernel.
Jan 10 23:01:52 IT096060 kernel: Disabling lock debugging due to kernel taint
Jan 10 23:01:52 IT096060 kernel: nvidia: module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing - tainting kernel
Jan 10 23:01:52 IT096060 kernel: nvidia: module license taints kernel.
Jan 10 23:01:52 IT096060 kernel: videodev: Linux video capture interface: v2.00
Jan 10 23:01:52 IT096060 systemd[1]: Starting modprobe@dm_mod.service - Load Kernel Module dm_mod...
```

A snippet from the nvidia logfile:

```
*** ls: -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1275146 2024-01-09 11:01:06.773886523 +0000 /var/lib/dkms/nvidia/535.146.02/6.5.0-14-generic/x86_64/log/make.log
DKMS make.log for nvidia-535.146.02 for kernel 6.5.0-14-generic (x86_64)
Tue  9 Jan 11:00:47 GMT 2024
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-6.5.0-14-generic'
make --no-print-directory -C /usr/src/linux-headers-6.5.0-14-generic \
-f /usr/src/linux-headers-6.5.0-14-generic/Makefile modules
warning: the compiler differs from the one used to build the kernel
  The kernel was built by: x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-13 (Ubuntu 13.2.0-4ubuntu3) 13.2.0
  You are using:           cc (Ubuntu 13.2.0-4ubuntu3) 13.2.0
```

There are clearly some other problems with the system as I was browsing the whole journal file, I'm getting errors about bluetooth and wifi devices, but I suspect these are not the culprit preventing me from booting here.

Edit:

The machine is a custom Dell Mobile Precision Workstation 5560 CTO - with a Intel Core i9-11950H vPro with Nvidia RTX A2000 graphics

I installed runelite via appimage before this happened, is it possible this caused the issue?

Comment: Have you tried selecting an older kernel in GRUB, if one is available?

Comment: Yeah, I tried each of the different options in the grub menu, only the recovery mode options work in terms of the getting terminal access. If I use 'journalctl -xb' I do see some nvidia kernel issues, something about a tainted kernel. Not sure how to fix this though

Comment: I have edited to add, what I think are relevant snippets from the journalctl -xb output, and the nvidia log file. I managed to get the whole thing on a flash drive though so I can paste everything if it is useful

Comment: What model is the laptop?

Comment: It is a custom Dell Mobile Precision Workstation 5560 CTO - with a Intel Core i9-11950H vPro with Nvidia RTX A2000 graphics

Comment: I can't find anything useful unfortunately. Looks like this laptop is Ubuntu certified: https://ubuntu.com/certified/202104-28892 May require a reinstall. If also fails with Live USB, there might be something failing in the hardware (e.g. faulty memory)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150814/discussion-between-moo-and-biomage).

Comment: Is the secure boot off?

Comment: Secure boot is disabled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I'm not entirely sure what happened, the fix was to reinstall GNOME desktop via

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-gnome-desktop
```

This seems to have fixed whatever the issue was.